# TLS ticket does not fit - Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, drag-and-drop

I'm following Stanford course CS193p about iOS mobile development (spring 2023, lecture 10).

In this lecture, speaker is showing how to drag and drop images from browser.

There is our View with drop destination:

```
private var documentBody: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
         ZStack {
            Color.white
            AsyncImage(url: document.background)
                .position(Emoji.Position.zero.in(geometry))
            ForEach(document.emojis) { emoji in
                Text(emoji.string)
                    .font(emoji.font)
                    .position(emoji.position.in(geometry))
            }
        }
        .dropDestination(for: URL.self) { urls, location in
            drop(urls, at: location, in: geometry)
        }
    }
}
```

And function that just sets the url as background image:

```
private func drop(_ urls: [URL], at location: CGPoint, in geometry: GeometryProxy) -> Bool {
    if let url = urls.first {
        document.setBackground(url)
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

In the lesson it works just fine, but I'm always getting this error:

> EmojiArt[11053:204768] [quic] quic_crypto_session_state_serialize [C1.1.1.1:2] [-f8dc53637d49a846] TLS ticket does not fit (6914 > 6144)

I'm expecting the dropped image to be set as background.

Comment: the error message relates to your emojis. you don't give any code for this `document` or how it relates to quiz/crypto/TLS. Comment out the `ForEach`lines 7-11 and see if the drag action works.